# Are Adobe AIR applications supported on Surface Pro 3?

Tags: air, adobe

I haven't been able to find a definite answer to whether Adobe AIR applications are supported on Microsoft Surface Pro 3? Miscellaneous links have suggested that you can install Adobe AIR but not sure if that implies that Adobe AIR applications can run on Surface Pro3.

Comment: Yes.  It runs on Windows so it can do AIR.  AIR goes on virtually all devices.  It's Windows with a touchscreen and less power than a desktop.  You can package AIR with your app so the user doesn't have to have AIR installed.

Comment: My understanding is that Adobe AIR does not run on Windows 8 Modern.

Comment: Wow.  Didn't even see that.  Microsoft is trying Silverlight again.  Sorry, never occurred to me Microsoft would try forcing Silverlight again.

Answer (score -1):

Surface  Pro 3 runs Windows 8 / 10, so any Adobe Air application will work.

The older Surface devices that run Windows RT wont run Air applications.